# Adding file date created to list

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I've been trying to edit a bit of code which gives a list of all files in all subfolders to also give me the date created in the next column but am unsure how. Here is the code i'm working with: It gets the file paths fine but not the file DateCreateds

```
 Sub startIt()

   Dim FileSystem As Object
   Dim HostFolder As String

   HostFolder = "C:\folderthing"

   Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)

 End Sub

 Sub DoFolder(Folder)


    Dim SubFolder
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
      DoFolder SubFolder
    Next

    i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Dim File
    For Each File In Folder.Files
      ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(i, 1), Address:= _
          File.Path, TextToDisplay:=File.Path
      ActiveSheet.Add TextToDisplay:=File.DateCreated

      i = i + 1

    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `FileDateTime(pathname)`? [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264782(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: I just tried this exact script.  The ActiveSheet line failed with an error.  Remming that out, it worked fine.  So I changed that line to:  Range("A1") = File.DateCreated.  This gave me the last date that it read.  I think your problem is in the ActiveSheet.Add.

Comment: As @durbnpoisn said, I think you need to replace this line `ActiveSheet.Add TextToDisplay:=File.DateCreated` with this `Cells(i, 2).value = File.DateCreated`

Comment: Regardless of the specific problem, this is neat code that can be used for making catalogs of music, picture, and video files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the *Date* in column **B**, then:

```
Sub startIt()

   Dim FileSystem As Object
   Dim HostFolder As String

   HostFolder = "C:\TestFolder"

   Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)

 End Sub

 Sub DoFolder(Folder)


    Dim SubFolder
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
      DoFolder SubFolder
    Next

    i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Dim File
    For Each File In Folder.Files
      ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(i, 1), Address:= _
          File.Path, TextToDisplay:=File.Path
      Cells(i, 2).Value = File.DateCreated

      i = i + 1

    Next


End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Holy crap.  That is the exact solution I was about to post.

Comment: @durbnpoisn  That is not surprising..........the way that **IIJHFII** posed the question *(with only one bad line in the code)* would drive a common approach to making an answer.

Comment: I just thought it was funny.  I did the exact same thing you did.  Reconstructed it in Excel and found a method that worked.  At least I now know what my entire "work" folder looks like when Excel reads it.