# check date of saved file (path given in cell) and return in next cell, vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create macro which will check if files given in column A exist and when they were saved. The macro will put date and time of saved file in column B.

PS. in column A will be given full path of the file, example C:\VBA\tandem\file1.xlsm

Thanks in advance for some help.

Comment: `find hint how to create macro` that's what google is for, not SO.

Comment: lol really? You want to play this game? Because my comment _still_ applies to `trying to create macro`.

Comment: i have searched in Google, but there is nothing that I am able to use, if there would be I wouldn't be asking here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding file date created to list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205588/adding-file-date-created-to-list)

Comment: You'll need to use a FIleSystemObject. Google VBA FIleSystemObject file information.  If you still need help, comeback and post your code.  We'll be happy to help.

Comment: Copy some code that you think is pertinent, paste it in a question, and ask for help figuring it out.  That is how  Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @ThomasInzina may I ask you something?

Comment: You just did.  But you can ask something else if you like.

Comment: Do dealers cheat in vegas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115463/discussion-between-thomas-inzina-and-findwindow).

Comment: @ThomasInzina thanks a lot I will look for this and how to use this object in VBA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim str As String
    For Each cell In Range("A2:A11")                 '-->enter your range here
        str = cell.Value
        If Dir(str) <> "" Then                       '-->check if file exists
            cell.Offset(0, 1) = FileDateTime(str)    '-->get date
        Else
            cell.Offset(0, 1) = "File doesn't exist"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

`FileDateTime` function returns the date and time a file was created or modified. See [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/filedatetime.php) for details.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this will help me a lot.

Comment: I'm going to put that one in my arsenal.